# use MySQL to update fields with group

Tags: mysql

```
id     item_id    item_order
---    ---------- -----------
1      1          0
2      1          0
3      1          0

4      2          0
5      2          0
6      2          0

7      3          0
8      3          0
9      3          0
10     3          0
```

How to use MySQL `statement` to update the `order` fields to:

```
id     item_id    item_order
---    ---------- -----------
1      1          1
2      1          2
3      1          3

4      2          1
5      2          2
6      2          3

7      3          1
8      3          2
9      3          3
10     3          4
```

Comment: That's not a very useful ID column

Comment: Please don't mention for the column. It's a simple version of my case. It's useful for me.

Comment: I clearly see no changes but the Field Filed witch is not a programming problem and extremely silly

Comment: OK, Forgive my unclearly English. I want to use the Console MySQL Utility to solve it, any idea? BTW, where's your last answer? deleted?

Comment: That's fine. I don't think it's a simple task by mysql statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subquery can provide an elegance solution.  Assuming your table is called `test`:

```
UPDATE test a SET item_order = ( 
  SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT id, item_id FROM test ) b
  WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id AND b.id <= a.id
)
```

How it works?  For each row it would query the number of rows with same item_id and lower or equal id.  This may be not as scalable as other solutions, I haven't tested, but for smaller tables this is easier to understand and update.

Notice that `b` is another subquery.  This would force MySQL to create an internal temp table so that it won't complain we are reading from the table we are updating.

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
create table tmp
(
  id int(10) unsigned,
  `order` int(10) unsigned auto_increment,
  ... // any other columns
 primary key (id, `order`)
);

insert into tmp select * from old_table; // you can specify order if you want to
```

after getting the `order` correctly,
you can then remove the primary key on two columns

---

***NOTE -- avoid reserved words as column name at all cost***

---

### IT WORKS

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+--------+
| id   | orders |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      0 |
|    1 |      0 |
|    1 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |
+------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into tmp select * from test;
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tmp;
+----+--------+
| id | orders |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      1 |
|  1 |      2 |
|  1 |      3 |
|  2 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |
|  2 |      3 |
|  2 |      4 |
+----+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc tmp;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(10) | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
| orders | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_incrent |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Cynial - you are drastically changing your question

Comment: yes, I did. I change it for clearly description and unnecessary discussion on SQL structure, but the essence is the same. As per your method, it really works. thanks.

Comment: np, and you will benefits from the auto increment in the future OR a disaster to maintain :)

Comment: depends ... this only fix for existing data and pretty neat, but if you are going accept more data in the future, an auto increment could be easier

Comment: OK. It's fit for me. Thank you at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

Select version:

```
select id,item_id,
@num:= if(@item_id=item_id,@num+1,1) as posit,
@item_id:=item_id as itid
from tab,(select @num:=0,@item_id:=0) as t order by item_id,id

+----+---------+-------+------+
| id | item_id | posit | itid |
+----+---------+-------+------+
|  1 |       1 |     1 |    1 |
|  2 |       1 |     2 |    1 |
|  3 |       1 |     3 |    1 |
|  4 |       2 |     1 |    2 |
|  5 |       2 |     2 |    2 |
|  6 |       2 |     3 |    2 |
|  7 |       3 |     1 |    3 |
|  8 |       3 |     2 |    3 |
|  9 |       3 |     3 |    3 |
| 10 |       3 |     4 |    3 |
+----+---------+-------+------+
10 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

Update version:

```
update tab as t1 
inner join ( 
select id,item_id,
@num:= if(@item_id=item_id,@num+1,1) as posit,
@item_id:=item_id as itid
from tab,(select @num:=0,@item_id:=0) as t order by item_id,id )
as t2 
set t1.item_order = t2.posit
where t1.id = t2.id

+----+---------+------------+
| id | item_id | item_order |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 |
|  2 |       1 |          2 |
|  3 |       1 |          3 |
|  4 |       2 |          1 |
|  5 |       2 |          2 |
|  6 |       2 |          3 |
|  7 |       3 |          1 |
|  8 |       3 |          2 |
|  9 |       3 |          3 |
| 10 |       3 |          4 |
+----+---------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```